# Why does my A-star algorithm not make progress

Tags: python, a-star, euclidean-distance

I am trying to make a fast path finding algorithm for ships and use the A*-algorithm therefore.
But it isn't working correctly as when i try to compute the path from (28.7, -77.55) to (55.85, 6.95) (which is about miami to denmark) and i start the algorithm, it always stays even after more then 30 minutes i am still at around (40, -70) although the path is barely blocked, and it should compute the path straight forward. I have a MongoDB database, which consists of Coordinates that are all on the water and where two that are next to each other have a distance of 0.05 degrees. Each Coordinate entry in the database has the values '_id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'neighbours'. 'neighbours' is a list of the ids of all neighbour coordinates.

One entry coud look like this:
`{'_id': ObjectId('638409951f8d66bb158869d1'), 'longitude': -77.55, 'latitude': 28.7, 'neighbour_ids': [ObjectId('638409451f8d66bb15883191'), ObjectId('638409951f8d66bb158869d0'), ...]`

```
class AStar:
    def __init__(self, start: tuple[float, float], target: tuple[float, float]):
        self.start = start
        self.target = target
        self.mongo_client = MongoCliSingleCol(connection="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017", db="earthgrid", coord_edge_collection="coordinates_edges_0p05")
        self.start_id = self.mongo_client.get_coordinate_id(start)
        self.target_id = self.mongo_client.get_coordinate_id(target)
        print(self.target_id)

    def execute_astar(self, h=euclidian_distance):
        frontier = []
        heapq.heappush(frontier, (0,self.start_id))
        came_from = {self.start_id: None}
        cost_so_far = {self.start_id: 0}
        while frontier:
            current_id = heapq.heappop(frontier)[1]
            self.mongo_client.print_coord(current_id)
            if current_id == self.target_id:
                return self.get_path_alt(came_from)

            for neighbour_id, distance in self.mongo_client.get_neighbours_with_dist(current_id, euclid=True).items():
                new_cost = cost_so_far[current_id] + distance
                if neighbour_id not in cost_so_far or new_cost < cost_so_far[neighbour_id]:
                    cost_so_far[neighbour_id] = new_cost
                    neighbour_db_coord = self.mongo_client.get_coordinate_by_id(neighbour_id)
                    neighbour_coord = neighbour_db_coord["latitude"], neighbour_db_coord["longitude"]
                    priority = new_cost + h(neighbour_coord, self.target)
                    heapq.heappush(frontier, (priority, neighbour_id))
                    came_from[neighbour_id] = current_id
        return False
```

The euclidian distance is calculated like this:

```
def euclidian_distance(start: tuple[float, float], target: tuple[float, float]):
    return geopy.distance.geodesic(start, target).km
```

I have tried using different heuristics, i used the debugger, but the distances calculated are always rational. I really have no clue what i am doing wrong. I hope i gave all important information that is necessary to get help. This is my first question on stackoverflow.

Best regards and thanks in advance
Markus

Comment: Looks pretty good to me.. have you tried the haversine distance as heuristic?

Comment: @lxg95 yes, i tried haversine, euclidean, manhattan